# python enumerate function getting index error

Tags: python

I don't understand why the enumeration below. It returns an index error. Since I don't need the index of the enumeration I'm using the under bar. For my understanding y isn't an index. Right? I don't recall where the under bar idea came from but I have used it in the past with good results. Here not so much.

```
PanelName = ['A1','A2','A3']
PnlCkts = [[1,3,5],[1,4,5],[1,2,4]]

for x in range(len(PanelName)):
    for _,y in enumerate(PnlCkts[x]):
        sql = ("SELECT Ckt, EObjName, Description, Location,"
            + " EObjType, PDF, Spec, "
            + "DwgName FROM EObjDump WHERE Panel = '"
            + PanelName[x]
            + "' AND Ckt = "
            + str(PnlCkts[x][y])
            + ";"
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

If you don't need the index, you don't need to use `enumerate(PnlCkts[x])`, just iterate over `PnlCtks[x]` directly.

Then you also don't need to use `PnlCkts[x][y]` below, `y` will already be one element from `PnlCkts[x]`.

```
for x in range(len(PanelName)):
    for y in PnlCkts[x]:
        sql = ("SELECT Ckt, EObjName, Description, Location,"
            + " EObjType, PDF, Spec, "
            + "DwgName FROM EObjDump WHERE Panel = '"
            + PanelName[x]
            + "' AND Ckt = "
            + str(y)
            + ";"
            )
```

But, you could actually use `enumerate` for the iteration over `PanelName`, since here you do need both the index and the value:

```
for x, panel in enumerate(PanelName):
    for y in PnlCkts[x]:
        sql = ("SELECT Ckt, EObjName, Description, Location,"
            + " EObjType, PDF, Spec, "
            + "DwgName FROM EObjDump WHERE Panel = '"
            + panel
            + "' AND Ckt = "
            + str(y)
            + ";"
            )
```

Here's a more advanced technique you might want to be aware of: Since you are processing first `PanelName[0]` and `PnlCkts[0]`, then `PanelName[1]` and `PnlCkts[1]`, and so on, you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) as an idiomatic way to iterate over the two lists in parallel:

```
for panel, ckts in zip(PanelName, PnlCkts):
    for y in ckts:  # I have no idea what the names mean so I invent one here
        sql = ("SELECT Ckt, EObjName, Description, Location,"
            + " EObjType, PDF, Spec, "
            + "DwgName FROM EObjDump WHERE Panel = '"
            + panel
            + "' AND Ckt = "
            + str(y)
            + ";"
            )
```